# CAGradientLayer is not being shown?

Tags: ios, swift, cagradientlayer

Ok, I have a collection view and a custom cell that I created using Xib file so that I could use the same cell in another collection view on a different view.  In my cellForItemAtIndexPath I have:

```
let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdenitifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! StoriesCollectionViewCell
cell.setCell(arrArticles[indexPath.item])

return cell
```

and inside my custom cell class in the setCell func :

```
func setCell(article : Article) {
    self.articleImageView.alpha = 0.0
    self.storyHeadline.text = article.headline

    //set the background for the txtView to a gradient, from clear to white
    let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
    gradient.frame = txtView.frame
    gradient.colors = [UIColor.clearColor().CGColor, UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor]
//        gradient.startPoint = txtView.frame.origin
//        gradient.endPoint = CGPointMake(txtView.frame.maxX, txtView.frame.maxY)
    self.txtView.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, atIndex: 0)

    //for testing purpose only, will be replaced by web service response
    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateStyle = .MediumStyle
    dateFormatter.timeStyle = .NoStyle

    self.storyHeadlineDate.text = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(article.date!)
    manager.imageForArticle(article) { (image) in
        self.articleImageView.image = image
        UIView.animateWithDuration(1, animations: {
            self.articleImageView.alpha = 1.0
        })
    }
    self.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0
}
```

everything is working like I want it to other than the gradient background color.  I was also wondering if there was a better delegate method to set this gradient in.  txtView is a UIView created and linked from the xib, btw.

Comment: Check gradient frame property, width, height...

Comment: yea i've checked that, at the time of being inserted into the sublayer, according to lldb print statement it is: width - 180.0, height - 35.0...which is correct as the txtView as the same, and both have the same x,y values

Answer (score 0):

try to write this code to tableViewCell file

```
override func didMoveToSuperview() {

    let screenWidth = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width
    gradientView.bounds.size.width = screenWidth
    let gradient: CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    gradient.frame = gradientView.bounds
    gradient.colors = [
        UIColor(hex: "#030303" ,alpha: 0).CGColor,
        UIColor(hex: "#030303"  ,alpha: 0.6).CGColor ]
    print("color set: ", gradient.colors)
    gradient.locations = [0.0, 0.6]
    gradient.opacity = 0.4

    gradientView.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, atIndex: 0)
    gradientView.layer.masksToBounds = true

}
```